# How to merge text lines split across several records in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I would like to merge the records in python pandas dataframe

Current Dataframe

```
Date        Value Date  Description     Amount
01/07/2019  01/07/2019  CHEQUE WITHDRAW     1000.00
01/07/2019  01/07/2019  SUNDRY CREDIT CAPITAL FUND FEES     100.00

02/07/2019  02/07/2019  CHEQUE WITHDRAW     10.00   
02/07/2019  02/07/2019  SUNDRY CREDIT FROM HEAD OFFICE      10.00                           

02/07/2019  02/07/2019  CHEQUE WITHDRAW     50.00   

Expected dataframe
Date        Value Date  Description                  Amount
01/07/2019  01/07/2019  CHEQUE WITHDRAW                      1000.00
01/07/2019  01/07/2019  SUNDRY CREDIT CAPITAL FUND FEES      100.00
02/07/2019  02/07/2019  CHEQUE WITHDRAW              10.00  
02/07/2019  02/07/2019  SUNDRY CREDIT FROM HEAD OFFICE       10.00                          
02/07/2019  02/07/2019  CHEQUE WITHDRAW                  50.00
```

Getting error KeyError: 26

I have tried to loop through rows and find the amount column null and merge with description and then drop the row

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if (pd.isnull(row[3]) == True):
    df.loc[index-1][2] = str(df.loc[index-1][2]) + ' ' + str(df.loc[index][0]) 
    df.drop([index],inplace=True)
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what your dataset actually looks like. Can you clarify it / format your sample?

Comment: Hi, since dataframe is not correctly formatted, please click the link for current dataframe and expected dataframe https://rsqpublic.s3.amazonaws.com/dataframe.png

Comment: Besides, if you really want to merge two dataframes, you'll probably want to take a look at `DataFrame.merge`

Comment: So you want to combine two dataframes so that the resulting dataset is composed by the rows of the two input dataframes? Please explain how do you exactly want you dataframes to be combined/joined/merged

Comment: it is single dataframe not two dataframes, please click updated image for https://rsqpublic.s3.amazonaws.com/dataframe_1.png

Comment: So what you want is to filter out rows with missing fields?

Comment: resolved it by looping through dataframe and copy into another dataframe row by row, not sure it is a ideal way

Comment: Can you change the title of this question e.g. like "How to merge text lines split across several records in pandas"? Merging usually means something different in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You could try that as follows (on the end of this posting, you can find my test data):

```
# create a new aux column "Description new" that will be filled with the
# new description
df['Description new']= df['Description']

# create an auxillary data frame copy that will be shifted
# to match the wrapped lines and add another aux column
# that just contains the wrapped and not yet added segments
df_shifted= pd.DataFrame(df, copy=True)
df_shifted['Continued Description']= df_shifted['Description'].where(df_shifted['Date'].isna(), None)

# it seems you have just up to 2 line breaks, so we would have to 
# do it just 2 times
for i in range(3):
    # shift the aux df to get the wrapped descriptions in the same line
    df_shifted= df_shifted.shift(-1)
    # concatenate them
    df['Description new']= df['Description new'].str.cat(df_shifted['Continued Description'].fillna(''), sep=' ').str.strip(' ')
    # delete the added parts from Continued Description in order
    # not to add them to the previous transaction's description
    df_shifted.loc[~df['Date'].isna(), 'Continued Description']= None

df.loc[~df['Date'].isna(), 'Description new']
```

This returns something like:

```
0                  CHEQUE WITHDRAW   
1    SUNDRY CREDIT CAPITAL FUND FEES 
4                  CHEQUE WITHDRAW   
5    SUNDRY CREDIT FROM HEAD OFFICE  
7                  CHEQUE WITHDRAW   
Name: Description new, dtype: object
```

You can test that with the data produced by the following code:

```
import io
csv="""
Date;Value Date;Description;Amount
01/07/2019;01/07/2019;CHEQUE WITHDRAW;1000.00
01/07/2019;01/07/2019;SUNDRY CREDIT;100.00
;;CAPITAL FUND;
;;FEES;
02/07/2019;02/07/2019;CHEQUE WITHDRAW;10.00
02/07/2019;02/07/2019;SUNDRY CREDIT;10.00
;;FROM HEAD OFFICE;
02/07/2019;02/07/2019;CHEQUE WITHDRAW;50.00
"""

df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv), sep=';')
```